# Writing new excel file without data from previous workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to write a programm to compare strings from a fixed matrix to 2 specific columns from an excel file. So far, I am first trying to achieve that a comparison with a match in row takes place. So far, the comparison of one string from the matrix is successful.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from IDM import idm_matrix


wb = xl.load_workbook('Auswertung_C33.xlsx')
sheet = wb['TriCad_Format']

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, 8)
    if idm_matrix[0][0] in cell.value:
         sheet.cell(row=2, column=1).value = cell.value
         wb.save('Auswertung.xlsx')
```

Question: How can I achieve that the matching values are saved in a new file WITHOUT the loaded workbook above?

For further help with this project I will get back to you as soon as I am facing more difficulties with the matrix comparison.

Thanks for your help.
Regards, Alex

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: The answer from henjiFire below worked for me. However, I noticed that  I need to copy the entire row when the cell value has a match. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a new workbook to save your answer (comparison result). something like below. Hope this is helpful.

```
    import openpyxl as xl
    from IDM import idm_matrix


    wb = xl.load_workbook('Auswertung_C33.xlsx')
    result_wb = xl.Workbook() #workbook to save your result.
    result_sheet = result_wb.active #get the active sheet to save your result.
    sheet = wb['TriCad_Format']

    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        row_list = []
        for col in range(1, sheet.max_col+1):
            cell = sheet.cell(row, col)
            row_list.append(cell)
            #adjust row,col offset to match your matrix index below, e.g. row-2, col-1. you might need another loop to loop through your matrix.
            if idm_matrix[i][j] in row_list:
                result_sheet.append(row_list)          
                result_wb.save('Auswertung.xlsx') #save the result workbook
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! How can I simply copy the entire row of the matching cell value?

Comment: @n1ce you can just copy cells with value via a for loop or list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I am still struggling to translate that in correct code.. Can you help me? By the way, I'm still a newbee in Python..

Comment: @n1ce I updated my answer to include a column loop so that every column in that row will be copied as well. However, I don't know how your matrix looks like. You need to adjust how `row`, `col` match to your matrix. Also, if you think the answer is helpful, it would be nice to accept it. :)

Comment: You are of great help. Right now only the matching value is copied in each column. However, I want to copy the entire row of the 1st excel with all different values (Strings) when there is a match in the specific column. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @n1ce my solution is to add cell value to a list so that later you can check value in matrix against that list, e.g. row_list. However, depending on how your matrix looks like, you may want to take make your first sheet row to a list of row list so you can easily loop through.

Comment: I had to make some minor adjustments, it works fine now, thanks again! I just need 2 more steps to achieve what I am actually looking for. 

Step 1: I want to take the second value of the matrix [0][1] and look for a match in column 15 in the row where I found the first value of the matrix. If both values are matching, the append function should copy the row.
Step 2: I want to iterate over the matrix to find all rows which contain both values in each row.

If you could help me with this last 2 steps I would appreciate it a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@henjiFire: Thats how the code looks like right now:

```
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    row_list = []
    for col in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
        cell = sheet.cell(row, col)
        row_list.append(cell.value)
        # adjust row,col offset to match your matrix index below, e.g. row-2, col-1. you might need another loop to loop through your matrix.
    if idm_matrix[0][0] in row_list:
        if row_list[14] is not None and idm_matrix[0][1] in row_list[14]:
                result_sheet.append(row_list)
```

Comment: so you only check 1 value in your matrix against row value?

Comment: I am just trying to understand the steps in between. As mentioned above I need to check a second value in column 15 from the matching row. Step 2 is the final step where I need to iterate over the entire matrix, where both values are always in a row.
Is there an easier way to prepare a separate file where 100x2 values are checked in the sheet?

Comment: i just added the check of the 2. value. However the final piece of looping through the matrix is missing.. I cannot figure it out :(